# how to add parameters in TSmartQuery in IntraWeb?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal, intraweb

How to add parameters in TSmartQuery?
I mean on the Parameter tab which can be seen when I click on params properties.

I found two ways:
-editing the dfm file
-parameters are filled out automatically based on used :vars in Sql tab.
I did not managed to add them manually using a user interface.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific than your question currently is.

Answer (score 2):

TSmartQuery is component from [ODAC](http://www.devart.com/odac) library.

TSmartQuery is similar to other TQuery family you can use parameters in different ways depend on your needs:

1. If you already used Sql with parameters such as: `Qry1.Sql.Text := 'Select * from Table where Id = :id';`
   then you can the defined parameter  values as : `Qry1.ParamByName('Id').asInteger := 10;`
2. If you have an instance from TParam you can add to the qry like : `Qry1.Params.AddParam(myParam).`
3. You can create Parameter and assigned directly to the ParamList with : `Qry1.Params.CreateParam();`

which defined as:

```
function CreateParam(FldType: TFieldType; const ParamName: _string;
  ParamType: TParamType): TDAParam;
```

2 & 3 mostly used with Stored Procedures because you need to define if the parameter will be input or output param.

**Update**:
  I didn't notice that you are using Intraweb when I post my answer, but it should be the same way as you do with normal Delphi applications.